# Rvest mailto with <a href="javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto(%27ocknvq%2Cjgkmg0qdgtnkpBwpk%5C%2Fvwgdkpigp0fg%27)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to extract emails with rvest from this [link](https://uni-tuebingen.de/fakultaeten/philosophische-fakultaet/fachbereiche/asien-orient-wissenschaften/indologie/mitarbeiter/)
However there is a javascript that masked the mailto href

How can I improve the following code?

```
 uni<- c("https://uni-tuebingen.de/fakultaeten/philosophische-fakultaet/fachbereiche/asien-orient-wissenschaften/indologie/mitarbeiter/")
  r<-read_html(uni) 
  a <- r %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>%
    html_attrs() %>%
    as.character() %>%
    str_subset("mailto:") %>%
    str_remove("mailto:")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like this page was especially designed to prevent the scraping of emails. You'd need to reverse engineer the javascript code that runs in browser of you want to scrape those values. Or maybe try something like RSelenium to run a web browser for you to evaluate the javascript.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick could you elaborate on "You'd need to reverse engineer the javascript code that runs in browser" what does it mean practically?

Comment: It would mean going to the site in your browser and opening your browser's developer tools. Then looking at all the requests being made and finding the javascript source code that the browser needs to run the `UnCryptMailto` function. My guess is the code is obfuscated to prevent easy decoding but you should step through with a javascript debugger to try to figure out how it works. But clearly the authors of that page wrote it so that email addresses could not be easily scrapped so I don't really want to encourage you to go against their wishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def decryptCharcode(n, start, end, offset):
    n = ord(n) + offset
    if (offset > 0 and n > end):
        n = start + (n - end - 1)
    elif (offset < 0 and n < start):
        n = end - (start - n - 1)

    return ''.join(map(chr, [n]))



def decryptString(enc, offset):

    dec = ""

    length = len(enc)

    for i in range(length-3):

        n = enc[i]
        if (0x2B <= ord(n) <= 0x3A):
            dec += decryptCharcode(n, 0x2B, 0x3A, offset)
        elif 0x40 <= ord(n) <= 0x5A:
            dec += decryptCharcode(n, 0x40, 0x5A, offset)
        elif (0x61 <= ord(n) <= 0x7A):
            dec += decryptCharcode(n, 0x61, 0x7A, offset)
        else:
            dec += enc[i]

    return dec

email = "%27ocknvq%2Cuvqemgt0ygtpgtBdnwgykp0ej%27" 
if "%27ocknvq%2C" in email:
    email = email.replace("%27ocknvq%2C","") 
email = decryptString(email,-2)

if "%3A%0D" in email:
    email=email.replace("%3A%0D","-")
```

print(email)

I converted the JS code to python.
Reference: https://gist.github.com/InsanityMeetsHH/c38f513f28d6f9b778912f110c565348

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: I converted the terms from JS to python.