# How do I decrypt email from the href value

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, encryption

I am trying to decrypt email from the href value.
I encountered this problem while doing a web scraping task using python.

```html
<a href="javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto(%27ocknvq%2CkphqBngjocpp0ej%27);">
```

[image: source]

Whenever I click on *Email*, it directs me to Outlook mail application.From there I can get the email.However, it want the email without actually going to the mail application and in the console.

I have tried various decryption methods discussed on this website but it didn't work.Can someone give me a hint about what type of method for encryption is used?

Comment: Usually email address get "encrypted" to prevent just that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to reverse engineer the encryption, you will need to go through the site's source and look for the JS function `linkTo_UnCryptMailto`.

More simply though, if you open dev tools (Ctrl + Shift + I) on chrome and click on the console, you should just be able to type `linkTo_UnCryptMailto(%27ocknvq%2CkphqBngjocpp0ej%27)` and view the result since the function appears to be global.

Comment: I got the github code by searching and converted the JS decryption part to python.I posted the code here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551024/rvest-mailto-with-a-href-javascriptlinkto-uncryptmailto27ocknvq2cjgkmg0qdg/67167970?noredirect=1#comment118730107_67167970

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Call `decryptString('ocknvq,kphqBngjocpp0ej', -2)` in browser's dev-tools.

**How to:**

As [@Akilan Manivannan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14970007/akilan-manivannan) mentioned, you can use the browser's dev-tools:

1. Open dev-tools with e.g. `right click` + `inspect` on page you found `linkTo_UnCryptMailto`
2. Select `Console` tab
3. Put only the function's name `linkTo_UnCryptMailto` and hit enter
4. This shows you that this method calls the method `decryptString` with the string and the number `-2` as parameter
5. [URL-decode](https://www.urldecoder.org/) string `%27ocknvq%2CkphqBngjocpp0ej%27` → `'ocknvq,kphqBngjocpp0ej'`
6. Call `decryptString` with both parameters (string & `-2`) in the console of the dev-tools:
   `decryptString('ocknvq,kphqBngjocpp0ej', -2)`

[image: use dev-tools to execute methods]

ℹ️ I think email addresses like this get "encrypted" (more like obfuscated) to make it more difficult for "bad bots" to find addresses which they then might spam.